# Nodejs Concurrency

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a general query regarding node concurrency. 
There's a simple api that does a read from ElasticSearch for a given field and it takes not more than 250ms. The node server is run on a Ec2 instance with 2 cores and so with advantage of clusters we have it running on both of those.
Using loadtest npm package we do a simple load test as follows

loadtest -c 16 --rps 5 api and it's within the expected range of 250ms.
Once the load is increased as
loadtest -c 32 --rps 5 api and it's exceeds range around 500ms-1s.

For a relatively simple api like this, is that the max no.of requests(80) that the 2 core instance can handle at max without performance hit? Does memory matter in this case 4GB vs 8gb? Or are we doing something wrong. I was always under the impression that nodejs is meant for handling such concurrent requests with relative ease.

Comment: Do these `-c 32 --rps 5`, `-c 16 --rps 5` settings make any sense? What is the point to have concurrency level **higher** than RPS? No wondering latency increased - most workers wait their order.

Comment: Got it. I was thinking that its just `32X5` or `16X5` requests made per sec. Switched to `-c 10 --rps 25` and the latency starts doubling at this point.